# DMARC says SPF fail even with SPF record

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, spf

I have the following SPF record under the pixelark.com domain:

```
v=spf1 ip4:70.164.0.71  include:amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

The ip4 address is the webserver, the amazonses.com is used for Amazon SES.  It is the amazon SES that is giving me the issue.

This is one of many example DMARC results I get when sending email through amazon SES.

```
<record>
 <row>
  <source_ip>204.197.248.33</source_ip>
  <count>1</count>
  <policy_evaluated>
    <disposition>none</disposition>
    <dkim>pass</dkim>
    <spf>fail</spf>
  </policy_evaluated>
 </row>
 <identifiers>
  <header_from>pixelark.com</header_from>
 </identifiers>
 <auth_results>
  <dkim>
    <domain>pixelark.com</domain>
    <result>pass</result>
  </dkim>
  <spf>
    <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
    <result>fail</result>
  </spf>
 </auth_results>
</record>
```

I am sending an email from noreply@pixelark.com through Amazon SES.  I have amazonses.com as a valid sender in the SPF record but the DMARC is showing an SPF fail.

I cannot figure out why this is happening?  I have not been able to figure this one out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your SPF record appears to be correct, however, `204.197.248.33` resolves to `texas.adwebcentral.com` and it doesn't appear to be one of [Amazon SES addresses](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxEH4YOF3YJG0L/Amazon-SES-IP-addresses). Do you have any idea why does your email has this source IP?

Comment: not sure why it would have that source - just sending through AWS SES Gateway

Answer (score 10):

From first glance this could be related to DMARC requiring your Mail From (return-path) and From address domains to match. When you use an Email Service Provider they will usually have their own email address to capture bounces, which causes DMARC to fail with SPF.

We built a free labs project to track DMARC results. It might help you discover more sources. You can see it at http://dmarc.postmarkapp.com.

Comment: I was seeing exactly this, showing up as `Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass; dkim=pass; dmarc=fail;` (in message received @gmail). Solution was to change the Return-Path as suggested. (And first discovered I had a problem through the Postmark DMARC tool -- thanks for that!)

Comment: AWS SES users: [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html) is an in depth explanation and steps to resolve this using Custom MAIL FROM Domain

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the email was sent from an IP address resolving to `texas.adwebvertising.com`. Often times you will find forwarded emails in your DMARC aggregate reports.

In this case the email seems to have been routed through AmazonSES and forwarded by the intended recipient. The receiving server of the forwarded message reports a failed SPF check, as expected for forwarded messages.

In the current configuration, the addition of AmazonSES to your domain's SPF record doesn't help, since the bounce address is set to the `amazonses.com` domain.

You can alter this configuration in AmazonSES to use a subdomain of your domain for the bounce address (return-path) on which SPF check is performed. That way it aligns with your domain and will PASS DMARC on SPF.